# How to build a debian package and automatically get all dependency libraries

Tags: ubuntu, setup-project, dpkg

I need to build a debian package for an executable that I wish to set up on several machines. Is it possible to create this package with:

- all dependencies for that executable (like shared libraries)
- install needed packages (like multiarch, ssl, etc)
- set up project directiry (like directories and some header files

I dont need the debian package to have the compile files, just the dependencies for the executable to run in that machine (assuming all machines are running the same debian version)

I see on the official ubuntu forums how to create a package but dont understand how I can do to get all dependencies and set up the machine to run that executable itself.

Any ideas anyone?

My system build: Ubuntu wheezy, GLIBC 2.13, 64bit
My executable details: c/c++ executable, 32bit

Comment: Debian packages are described in a special formatted text file, that contains (among other things) a list of all dependencies. It's in other words *not* handled automatically, it's all manual.

Comment: ok but if I add the list of the dependencies in that text file, will it set those dependencies on the machine being installed on?

Comment: The package manager will attempt to install the packages you list as dependencies when your package is installed, unless they're already installed.

Comment: and is it possible to include directory structure as well when making a debian package?

Answer (score 1):

Looks, like you already have compiled binary and want make a .deb package to automatically setup all required packages. If so, than [the answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/279686/how-to-package-a-simple-bash-script) might help you.

All required packages should be listed in the `Depends:` variable of the .deb [control](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/dreq.en.html#control) file.

Package directory structure could be created/altered using .deb install file. See [install documentation](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/dother.en.html#install)